# how to configure proxy server (squid) to certain link

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, squid, http-proxy

I need to configure a proxy server:

1. which will allow my clients to connect to my proxy server then
2. they will be able to see a login page.

When I asked some IT gurus they told me "configure the forwarding url in proxy".

How do I achieve this? What kind of proxy should I use?

Comment: Are you trying to set up a WiFi hotspot, an internal proxy for a company, or something else?

Comment: Hi Michael, no i m not trying to set up Wifi, yes i m setting a proxy, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any hotspot services? Like Chilli Spot, etc.

Also you may be interested in special distros for routers which include such features including hotspot out-of-box: pfSense, m0n0wall, mikrotik, etc.

Comment: I remember working with M0n0wall before, how do i set it to forward clients to particular location..

Comment: Generally, you can redirect all forward traffic which goes to dest.port 80/tcp (for example) to the local port where you have your own proxy with your own rules, or http-server with login script, or anything else (depends on your config)

Comment: So you saying if i configure (in this case squid) http_server with a url it will forward all the traffic to that particular link ?

Comment: In your particular case: 1) Redirect all http-traffic from unauthorized users to your http-server with an authorization engine; block all other thraffic; 2) Once client passed the check, auth engine adds forward rule for him in firewall, and excludes the client from auth page redirect rules. In other words, it's a combination of firewall, http-server and some auth engine. All hotspot services work this (or similar) way.

Comment: In other words, you can set redirect to auth engine (http-server) with firewall rules for all clients by default, and auth engine should manage redirects/allow/forbidden rules for particular clients through firewall rules modification. As for 'squid login page' you've asked for, squid doesn't provide such feature. All you can do with out of box it is to disable transparent mode, switch the http authorization on and manually set this squid server as proxy in clients' browsers along with users credentials (login/pass) to access it.